# CMD cannot read input characters correctly

Tags: c++, cmd

I tried to use system function to run a cmd command, but I can't get the command output, Because My Windows is Italian When I type / in my system() function to call cmd its getting actually - and not getting / I tried this in my cmd and is receiving this - instead / ,I tried to use chcp 437 for English cmd but , it didn't work

example :

```
system("net user xxx xxxx /add");
```

the command is getting :

```
net user xxx xxxx -add
```

I just do not want to do this to work in Italian Windows and work for other languages actually, how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on Windows terminal, and too lazy to fire up my Windows VM to check, right now -- but does Windows terminal actually implement these very Linux bash-like `&&` command pipelines?

Comment: actually its getting && Instead // and getting / instead -  so my code be exactly like cgcp437 //net user xxx xxx -add and I don't about your questions

Comment: Is there a space between the `chcp` and its argument `437`, and a space before and after the double ampersand?  Additionally if the `chcp` command fails then your `net user` command will not run. Verify your code. Ensure the && are encoded in ASCII  and SWITCHCHAR is unset

Comment: yes that's my mistake, fixed , how to do that? there is no better option for doing it in c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should never use `system()`. You are programming in C++. There is no need to use `system()` since you have access to everything in the, well, system :D. `system()` was written in C after all.
  And there is the security risk: someone could replace `system()` or the command you are trying to run using `system()` in your machine and make *not-nice-things* in your system.
- you can change the code page in your code before calling `system()` using
  `SetConsoleOutputCP();` that lives in windows.h
  1252 is the Latin codepage and should do ok in Italian. Also 65001 is the utf-8 codepage and should also work well
- to run your program on the "new" Windows Terminal is also an option since it is Unicode
- pass a string to `system()` and not a literal. this way you can be sure it has what you want, before the call.
- it is a good practice to save the codepage in use before change and restore it on exit

#### A C++ Example

This program

- takes an array of commands

```
    const char* command[] =
    {
        "DIR .\\*.* /O:D",
        "NET USER /Add /?"
    };
```

and runs on the console. The commands uses slashes and backslashes and outputs text so you can test a bit more. And you can just edit the array and add new commands to test

You can try alternative codepages. Here I used 65001, the one for Unicode

```
    int originalOCP = GetConsoleOutputCP();
    std::cout << "Original CodePage: " << originalOCP << "\n";
         
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    std::cout << "CodePage now is " << GetConsoleOutputCP() << "\n";
```

- The command is written on the console before being passed to `system()`

```
        std::cout <<
            "\n\n\t==> command " <<
            i << " is '" <<
            command[i] << "'\n\n";

        system(command[i]);
```

#### The output in Portuguese Windows

```
Original CodePage: 850
CodePage now is 65001


        ==> command 0 is 'DIR .\*.* /O:D'

 O volume na unidade C não tem nome.
 O Número de Série do Volume é 7E52-1BF2

 Pasta de C:\Users\toninho\source\repos\ConsoleApplication8\ConsoleApplication8

29/10/2020  10:21               168 ConsoleApplication8.vcxproj.user
29/10/2020  10:38               974 ConsoleApplication8.vcxproj.filters
29/10/2020  10:38             7.199 ConsoleApplication8.vcxproj
29/10/2020  10:59               676 a.cpp
29/10/2020  10:59    <DIR>          ..
29/10/2020  10:59    <DIR>          .
29/10/2020  10:59    <DIR>          Debug
               4 arquivo(s)          9.017 bytes
               3 pasta(s)   128.838.795.264 bytes disponíveis


        ==> command 1 is 'NET USER /Add /?'

A sintaxe deste comando é:

NET USER
[nome de usuário [senha | *] [opções]] [/DOMAIN]
         nome de usuário {senha | *} /ADD [opções] [/DOMAIN]
         nome de usuário [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN]
         nome de usuário [/TIMES:{horários | ALL}]
         nome de usuário [/ACTIVE: {YES | NO}]

CodePage now is 850
```

#### The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* command[] =
    {
        "DIR .\\*.* /O:D",
        "NET USER /Add /?"
    };

    int originalOCP = GetConsoleOutputCP();
    std::cout << "Original CodePage: " << originalOCP << "\n";
         
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    std::cout << "CodePage now is " << GetConsoleOutputCP() << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(command) / sizeof(char*); i += 1)
    {
        std::cout <<
            "\n\n\t==> command " <<
            i << " is '" <<
            command[i] << "'\n\n";

        system(command[i]);
    };

    SetConsoleOutputCP(originalOCP);
    std::cout << "CodePage now is " << GetConsoleOutputCP() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may write an example, I tried to do as u said But I did not succeed mr @arfneto

Comment: @Malek I edited the response to add an example. Today I have a bit of time